# Install ghostscript on load balanced Aws Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-elb

I am using ghostscript on my current server. Now I am moving to an Aws beanstalk server with Application load balancer.

How do I configure start-up script on elastic beanstalk so whenever a new instance is created by the load balancer, ghostscript is automatically installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control what's installed in ElasticBeanstalk instances with [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) file.

Whenewher Elastic Beanstalk creates a new EC2 instance, it will run all commands from the file in order to provision instance.

Example of **.ebextensions** file for installing Ghostscript

```
packages:
  yum:
    ghostscript: []
```

This will install a version of **ghostscript** from **yum** repository.

If you need a never version of ghostscript - it is also possible to specify installation shell commands inside ebextensions file. For example, [these commands will install Ghostscript 9.23](https://gist.github.com/digitalm/ac809eaac12f9899e5a60a17e5453520)